# Signal processing and properties question

Tags: signal-processing

We have the relationship between input and output: $Y(k)=|x(k+1)| + x(k)+ kx(k-5)$.

Find the output of the system when $x(k)=d(k)$.

What does this output represent?

Show if the system is linear, invariant, causal, stable, etc

Edit : I am familiar with sistem properties ,but what I mostly dont understand in the question is how to find the output when when $x(k)=d(k)$ and what it represents.To be more clear,what does it *mean* when when $x(k)=d(k)$.

Comment: Have you put any thought into the question yourself?

Comment: Is $d(k)$ the discrete impulse function, i.e. $d(0) = 1, d(k) = 0$ otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d(k)=\delta(k)$, i.e. the discrete unit impulse, then the response of the system to the input $x(k)=\delta(k)$ is its *impulse response*. However, since the system is not linear and time-invariant, it is not fully characterized by its impulse response. These are the system's properties:

- it is *non-linear*, because the absolute value is used to compute the output signal
- it is *time-varying*, because the time index $k$ appears as a multiplicative constant in the system equation.
- it is *non-causal*, because in order to compute $y(k)$ the input at time $k+1$ must be known.
- it is not BIBO-stable, because even for a bounded input, the output is not bounded due to the multiplicative constant $k$ which grows without bounds.

Comment: How do I find the impulse response?

Comment: @fsdd: Use $x(t)=\delta(t)$ and compute $y(t)$.

Comment: $Y(k)=|d(k+1)| + d(k)+ kd(k-5)$=
{ 0 for x ≠ 0 
and 
2+ k for x=0.}
Is this correct?